# How to combine elements of a matrix without using the same row more than once each time

Tags: c#, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

My goal is to combine those elements (Each letter stands for a different string)

```
A;B;F;...
X;C;D;...
P;O;K;...
...
```

in a textbox in every possible way without repetition and without combining elements of the same row. Dots represent continuation. So if the Matrix was just

```
A;B
X;C
```

The result should be AX AC BX BC. If it was

```
A;B;F
X;C;D
P;O;K
```

The result would be AXP AXO AXK ACP ACO ACK ADP ADO ADK BXP ....

I found an algorithm

```
private void buildAllCombinationsRecursive<TSource>(IList<TSource> i_targetList, IList<TSource> i_sourceList, int i_currentPos)
{
    if (i_currentPos == i_targetList.Count)
    {
        string combination = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < i_targetList.Count; i++)
        {
            combination += i_targetList[i] + " ";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(combination);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < i_sourceList.Count; i++)
    {
        i_targetList[i_currentPos] = i_sourceList[i];
        this.buildAllCombinationsRecursive(i_targetList, i_sourceList, i_currentPos + 1);
    }
}
```

But it creates a ABC CBA etc, that I don't need.

Comment: that algorithem can work, to do what you asked you will have to send your source list that genereted on the first iteration to the target list after deleted the row used so it will do the same process just with the 2nd row this time.

Comment: @DanielNetzer Kannst du das als Code darsellen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Eric Lippert's [C# Cartesian product Recursion](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/).

Each one of your 'matrix' lines will be a sequence in a recursion step.

The accumulator function will be string concatenation. Even though, for performance sake you could go for [StringBuilder.Append](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.append(v=vs.110).aspx).

[Example on rextester](http://rextester.com/IYQQ97704)

Comment: Please share an example on how to use `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)` with my problem.

Comment: I don't think the purpose of this site is to provide complete solutions, but ideas. I edited the answer.

Comment: I do think the purpose of this site is to provide complete solutions aswell as ideas. Thanks for editing the answer.